# Android No elements showing

Tags: android

I am trying to create an auto update program for my ROM.
So, I'm working on reading XML values from a url,
but when I run it, the activity shows nothing.
As I am fairly new to android coding, please describe clearly.

Code:

```
package com.defyworks.defyupdater;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class XMLParse extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView UpdateName[];
        TextView Version[];
        TextView download[];

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.defyworks.com/DefyROM/update.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            UpdateName = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            Version = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            download = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                UpdateName[i] = new TextView(this);
                Version[i] = new TextView(this);
                download[i] = new TextView(this);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("UpdateName");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                UpdateName[i].setText("Update Name : " + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Version");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                Version[i].setText("Version : " + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                download[i].setText("URL : " + websiteElement.getAttribute("download"));

                layout.addView(UpdateName[i]);
                layout.addView(Version[i]);
                layout.addView(download[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion : " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you are getting "`NetworkOnMainThreadException`". As already posted, you should open a new thread, probably via [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
However, that's not all. I downloaded your `input.xml` file, put it in assets folder and still there were multiple issues.

1. You are searching for `"item"`, but there is no such thing in the XML. So I changed `<version>` tag to be `<item>`.
2. Then I got `NullPointerException`, as you are looking for `Version`, where in the XML, the tag doesn't start with the capital `V`
3. Finally, for the download link you should use something like the following, according to your own programming style:

```
    NodeList downloadList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("download");
    Element downloadElement = (Element) downloadList.item(0);
    downloadList = downloadElement.getChildNodes();
    download[i].setText("URL : " + downloadList.item(0).getNodeValue());
```

Comment: I mean to show the download link you should use the code I posted, rather than your own code. What you should do to test this locally, e.g. without AsyncTask, is to take the XML, put it in assets folder & instead of `url.openStream()` do `getAssets().open("input.xml")`. When you are sure the UI works properly, only then fix the network code

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting exception and hence your `LinearLayout` doesn't contains any child.
The exception is because you are hitting URL in app's main thread which is not allowed.
Check your logs `XML Pasing Excpetion` must be printed somewhere in your logs.

You should use `AsyncTask` or any other mechanism( which sends the request in another thread) for your job.